# Penalty Factor for Adaptive Group LASSO

Tags: lasso

So [gglasso](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/gglasso/vignettes/Introduction_to_gglasso_package.html) in R appears to allow the user to implement adaptive group lasso by specifying group-wise penalty factors as you would with a typical adaptive lasso. Typically, when I want to train an adaptive lasso then I train a ridge regression and use the ridge coefficients more or less like [this](https://rpubs.com/kaz_yos/alasso), but in this situation I'm a little unsure how to get my penalty factors since I'm using a group-wise penalties. Can anyone enlighten me? I believe it's possible because I've seen several papers on the topic but haven't been able to access any of them.

Thanks!

Comment: Fellow Nate, one approach would be to use $\frac{1}{\sqrt{\sum_{p\in\mathcal{G}} \hat{\beta}^2_p}}$ where $\hat{\beta}_p$ is the ridge estimate of the pth variable, that is, to use the inverse $\ell_2$ norm of each group's ridge estimate as your groupwise penalty coef.